# Visual Studio 2012 Highlight all open files in solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, solution-explorer

Question:
Is there a way to make all files that are open in visual studio be highlighted in the solution explorer? 
(I know there is a filter that you can filter it to show only open files but this dos me no good sense I am looking for a file that may not be open, I am not even sure what the name of the file is until I open it up and say there it is.)

Example Imagined GUI result: (Different colors are fine) 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B31DHM9TkK99S3pWSms3QXR2Qk0/edit?usp=sharing
(image of what i am thinking, can not post image right now)

**Solution Explorer** 
-Solution
     +Stuff
     +More stuff
     -Code
          +MyOpenFile.cs (Highlighting)
          +MyNotOpenFile.cs
          +MyOtherOpenFile.cs (Highlighting)
          +MyCurrentlyOpenFile.cs (Highlighting, maybe a different color)

(the one with the red under line could be the active tab)

Background:
I don't know if this happens to any one else, but I have been doing it a lot for years now. While working on something I go to open up a file in the solution explorer and it turns out that the file is already open, and so visual studios just sets that file as the active tab. If I were working In just one window that would be fine, but I have few tab windows open beyond the main window and they are normally on a diffident monitor, so when the tab becomes active I do not see it at all, because it is not on the main window. This is even worse when I go to preview a file.

Icing on this cake:
-If it would have an option to highlight the parent nodes of open files, i the example "controllers" and "content" folders would be highlighted as well.
-If there was something that would do this for vs 2010 as well would be great.

I am looking for all most any thing at this point, an extension, a style sheet some where to edit, or as a last resort a good reference to a "How to code Extensions for Visual studios" website.

Edit: 
As a point Of clarification I am not looking for a way to locate a specific file in the solution explorer, I am looking for a way to make the files that are open look visually different, so that I know to look around a bit before thinking that VS2012 is crashing or the file is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

try an extension called VS commands. It will help you locate the files in solution.

Or this extension:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But nether show the open files Visually different and mixed with the up-open files.